# Where is the Update billing url?

Tags: wordpress, civimember, recurring-contributions

we are on Civi 5.8 and Wordcpress 5.

A member called and wants to change her credit card information for her recurring membership.  I would prefer to send her a link to click so she can change it herself.  Does anyone know what the URL is?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If they get the email receipts or have the initial email that notifies it is recurring it has the URL.

This is what I see for WP:

https://example.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Fupdatebilling&reset=1&**crid=XX**&**cs=......**

crid is the in the civicrm_contribution_recur table

Not sure what CS string is.

Comment: CS is a checksum, which in this usage means the link is only valid for a certain time (for security reasons). After that time you need to give a new link with a new checksum.

Comment: Actually for "updatebilling" that particular checksum might have infinite lifetime, so it's just a secondary access check, to prevent random people from updating anyone's billing info. But it's still based on a timestamp of when the link was generated, so isn't a fixed string.